# SFML 2.1 and variable's values error

Tags: variables, c++11, sfml

This is absolutly incomprehensible.

First I have this fonction :

```
void RenderSystem::onDraw( sf::RenderWindow& window, const sf::IntRect& viewRect ) {

    for(auto it = mComponents.begin() ; it != mComponents.end() ; ++it) {
        if ( viewRect.intersects( sf::IntRect( it->second->getGlobalBounds() ) ) )
            window.draw(*it->second);
    }
}
```

which is called by this one :

```
void Game::onDraw()
{
    mWindow.clear(sf::Color(208,244,247));
    mWindow.setView(mCamera);

    SystemManager::instance()->getSystem<RenderSystem>()->onDraw( mWindow, mCamera.getCameraBounds()); 
    mWindow.setView(mWindow.getDefaultView());
    mWindow.display();
}
```

I got a simple problem : in RenderSystem::onDraw, the values of viewRect.left, .top, .width and .height are not the good ones, and seems random. I tried that :

```
void Game::onDraw()
{
    mWindow.clear(sf::Color(208,244,247));
    mWindow.setView(mCamera);

    const sf::IntRect cCoordCamera = mCamera.getCameraBounds();

    SystemManager::instance()->getSystem<RenderSystem>()->onDraw( mWindow, cCoordCamera );
    mWindow.setView(mWindow.getDefaultView());
    mWindow.display(); 
}
```

and... it works perfectly. I don't understand why...

Any ideas ?

PS : GCC4.7 with Code::Blocks12 on Win7 32bits

Comment: What does `getCameraBounds` return?
Also:
    `for(auto it = mComponents.begin() ; it != mComponents.end() ; ++it) {`

Are you sure you want to copy every element in mComponent? Consider using `const auto&`.

Comment: getCameraBounds return an const sf::IntRect&.

Comment: Thanks for auto&, didn't know about that ^^

Comment: Change that return type to `sf::IntRect` and retry. Returning a temporary value as a  `non-const&` from a function is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCameraBounds()` returns `sf::IntRect&`.

```
class YourCamera {
    sf::IntRect intrect;

    // v--- Valid behavior ---v
    sf::IntRect getValid() { return intrect; } // returns intrect (copy or move)
    sf::IntRect& getValid2() { return intrect; } // returns a reference to intrect
    sf::IntRect getValid3() { sf::IntRect temporary; return temporary; } // returns a temporary IntRect (copy or move)
    sf::IntRect getValid4() { return sf::IntRect{...}; } // returns a temporary IntRect (copy or move)

    // v--- Undefined behavior ---v
    sf::IntRect& getInvalid2() { sf::IntRect temporary; return temporary; } // returns an invalid reference to temporary: undefined behavior
    sf::IntRect& getInvalid3() { return sf::IntRect{...}; } // returns an invalid reference to temporary: undefined behavior
};
```

I suspect `getCameraBounds()` is similar to `getInvalid()` in my example. You cannot return a non-`const&` value from a function if it is a temporary: its lifetime it's not long enough and it results in undefined behavior.

---

Unrelated:

```
for(auto it = mComponents.begin() ; it != mComponents.end() ; ++it) {
```

Your loop copies all elements of `mComponents`, because you are using `auto` instead of `auto&` or `const auto&`. I suppose you don't want to copy all your components every frame, but only "observe" them (use `const auto&`) or modify them (use `auto&`).

Comment: Hum, nope, my getCameraBounds() is similar to your getValid : `const sf::IntRect& Camera::getCameraBounds() const {
 return sf::IntRect( this->getPosition().x, this->getPosition().y, this->getSize().x, this->getSize().y );
}`

Comment: No, it is not. You're creating a temporary `sf::IntRect` and returning it. It is destroyed at the end of the `getCameraBounds()` scope.

Comment: @MathieuBattier: added more examples in my answer.

Comment: Hum yep. I tried some stuff, and retuning a `const sf::IntRect` works.

Comment: Never return non-reference types by const. You inhibit the compiler's chance to perform return value move optimizations. Either return by non-const value or by const reference. - This is basic C++ though: consider learning the core language before using SFML.

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere ^^. I can't learn everything by only reading stuff, and full-console programming become boring with the time. But anyway you're right, I'm far from mastering all c++. And I keep learning it.